# How do you spell maila?

Tags: language

I've looked in [the Jewish Languages dictionary](http://jel.jewish-languages.org/) and other places but I can't find anyone who gives a Hebrew spelling of the word maila,‎ meaning positive quality,‎ opposite of חסרון.‎ I'm guessing that it is מעלה from the root עלה meaning upwards or high quality,‎ but I can't seem to find it a dictionary.‎

Thanks!

[To the person who deleted this,‎ I hear the point,‎ but this is a question about a spoken word in Yeshiva culture,‎ not about Hebrew generally,‎ so I think it is germane.]

Comment: Are you talking about something pronounced *ma-ilah* or *my-lah* or something from the aramaic?

Answer (score 2):

Ah,‎ I think I found it in [Klein's](https://www.sefaria.org/Klein_Dictionary%2C_%D7%9E%D6%B7%D7%A2%D6%B2%D7%9C%D6%B8%D7%94.1?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)

מַעֲלָה f.n. 1 step, stair. 2 ascent. MH 3 grade, degree. NH 4 virtue, merit. [From עלה (= to go up, ascend). For the pref. see מַ◌.]

Comment: Correct. That's Ashkenazim trying to make up for not pronouncing the 'ayin. (Just as some say "Yaykov.")